# Delphi ADO dataset Filter

Tags: performance, delphi, ado

In an application I am building at work, I have a large database with a table say "People" with 100,000 + rows. Furthermore the entries in this table contain two types of data :
Parent type and Child type, where each Child type entry has the database id of its parent in a special "Child_OF" column.

In memory, both db entry types are represented by corresponding classes "TParent" and "TChild", where each parent class has the field "children : TList".

Which is the fastest way, using ADO, to:
- create a list of Parents and correctly assign to them their children...

The way I see it... one can go about the problem by 
1) retrieve in a bulk( by one sql query) all parents from the table and create the parents list with empty children lists.
2) retrieve in a bulk all children and for each parent try to find his/her children from the corresponding dataset.

Here is an example of what I have in mind for the assignment stage of the program...

```
procedure assignParentsTheirChildren(parentList: TList<TParent>;
  ma_people: TADOTable);
var
  i: Integer;
  qry: TADOQuery;
  aChild: TChild;
  aParent: TParent;
begin

  // create the query
  qry := TADOQuery.Create(nil);
  qry.Connection := ma_people.Connection;
  // set the sql statement to fetch all children ...
  qry.SQL.Clear;
  qry.SQL.Add('Select * from ' + ma_people.TableName + ' WHERE ChildOF <> ' +
    QuotedStr(''));
  // supposedly do some optimization---
  qry.CursorLocation := clUseClient; // load whole recordset in memory
  qry.DisableControls;
  // disable controls ensures that no dataset bound control will be updated while iterating the recordset
  qry.CursorType := ctStatic; // set cursor to static
  // open dataset
  qry.Open;
  // ***EDIT*** for completeness I add the suggestion made by Agustin Seifert below
  qry.RecordSet.Fields['ChildOf'].Properties.Item['Optimize'].value := true;

  for i := 0 to parentList.count - 1 do
  begin
    // get daddy
    aParent := parentList[i];

    qry.Filter := 'ChildOF = ' + QuotedStr(IntToStr(aParent.parentID));
    qry.Filtered := true;

    while (not qry.EOF) do
    begin
      aChild := TChild.Create;
      getChildFromQuery(aChild, qry); // fills in the fields of TChild class...
      aParent.children.Add(aChild);
      qry.Next;
    end;

  end;
  qry.Free;
end;
```

I guess the biggest bottleneck of the above code is that I am filtering the data for every new parent. Is there a faster rework using seek() or locate/find...? Basically one can assume that my dataset is static (during the time of creating the parents list) and network latency infinite:) (that is, I first want to do the child to parent assignment from memory). 
Many thanks!

btw I am  using Microsoft SQL Server 2012.

Comment: Do you really need to load all the parents and children into memory at once? You could implement a lazy loading mechanism and just populate the parents list with minimal info, then load up the extended detail (like child information) as and when you need to.

Comment: @Andy_D  yes.. unfortunately, I need to work on all the parents and children at the same time.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you don't wanna change your code/logic, there's a way to optimize filter, find, sort operations in ADO.
Access the recordset an optimize the involved fields:

```
var
  qry: TADOQuery;
  rs: _Recordset;
  ...
begin
  ...
  //after qry.Open;
  rs := qry.Recordset;
  rs.Fields['YourField'].Properties.Item['Optimize'].Value := True; //YourField = ChildOF in your case
```

This will create an index for the field. It takes a small amount of time vs the time it takes to filter lot of times without an index.

[msdn: Optimize Property-Dynamic (ADO)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms677521%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: Thank you! This small optimization procedure gave me a 10-fold or more speedup! I definitely recommend it. Lets see if there will be other suggestions.

Comment: Yes! It's great, your logic still the same and you don't need test it again. Its transparent.